# loading all the CollectionViewCells using willDisplay forItemAt delegate function

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have special content that I load in my CollectionViewCells from a server. This content takes a few seconds to finish loading. My issue is that once a cell is loaded, and I start scrolling my collection view, it is removed once it is not visible and needs to load again from the server, since `collection​View(_:​cell​For​Item​At:​)` is called again. In apple docs I see this message:
[image]

I found that note here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1771771-isprefetchingenabled

I am not sure if I am on the correct track here, but I thought this function may help me "hack" the system to load all the cells and never deque them, so I achieve the result of scrolling my collection view back and forth and not have cells reload.
Is there a way to do that using the function `collection​View(_:​will​Display:​for​Item​At:​)`? Is it possible to do it otherwise? any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading the content from the server?  If it hasn't changed, it will likely be cached locally, so you don't need to contact the server again.

Comment: I am loading it through the SDK of the supplier of the service I am using. I have no controll over it

Comment: What library or API are you using in swift to make the requests?  For example, `URLRequest` has `URLRequest.CachePolicy` - https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy.  This means that while the request is made, it will likely be filled by the local cache.  AlamoFire handles this as well.  AlamoFireImage can handle image caching as well.

Comment: Alternatively, you can either cache your data, or your views.  Load your data before you display your CollectionView, and then you can even create all your views and store them in memory.  Then, attach them to CollectionViewCells.  In this way, you are just using CollectionView for optimized scrolling, and not for view creation.  Depending on how many views you have, this may result in very high memory use.  I would recommend testing with request caching first.

Comment: It is actually blackbox to me so I cannot know anything happening behind the scene of the server. That is why I wanted to just load once and not call the server again. Actually I understand this is not acceptable attitude for an iOS app, since if the user has many (for example 300) cells, the app will have a very bad user experience. So I guess even if I get an answer, it will not be applicable by Apple

Comment: @dmorrow thanks for your advice, I will look into a way to implement that.

Comment: My recommendation has nothing to do with the server (unless it is not sending proper caching headers in its response).  Everything I have suggested is on the iOS side.

Comment: yes, I know and it is exactly the sort of solution I am looking for. thank you